# the directional derivative along the direction $L=-3i-4 j$ has the maximum value of 10

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $a,b$ be a real number, and function $z=2+ax^2+by^2$ in the directional derivative at the point$(3,4)$, the directional derivative along the direction $L=-3i-4j$ has the maximum value of 10.

Question: What is the value of $a$ and $b$?

This question is really hard for me,I know partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ are $2ax$ and $2by$ respectively. Substitute point $(3,4)$ in $\nabla z(x,y)=6ai + 8b j$,then $\sqrt{(6a)^2+(8b)^2}=100$. This  solves  $a=1, b=1$ and $a=-1, b=-1$, but the answer will be $a=-1,b= -1$. I don't know how to do this topic, ask God to give pointers, I have thought for a long time.

Comment: 1)Please reword the question, it is really hard to understand 2) What specifically you are question?

Comment: @AjayMishra Ok,

Comment: @AjayMishra I don't know how to calculate the values ​​of a and b.

Comment: Please don't roll back edits, I had edited the question to make it more readable. Use either \mathbf or \vec for denoting that the quantities are vectors.

Comment: @AjayMishra oh i see I thought it was garbled.I just used it, I don't know if you can edit the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fact:

> Maximum value of directional derivative of a function $f$ at point $P$ is obtained in the same direction of the gradient vector of function $f$ at the point $P$.

Let $ \mathbf L$ be the vector along the directional derivative is maximized, then implication of the fact is $$ \nabla f(x,y) = \lambda \mathbf L    $$ Where $\lambda$ is scalar

Now, $$ \nabla_{\mathbf L} f(x,y) = \nabla f(x,y) \cdot \cfrac{\mathbf L}{ |\mathbf L|}$$
$$ = \lambda \mathbf L \cdot  \cfrac{\mathbf L}{ |\mathbf L|} = \lambda |\mathbf L|$$

Here $z = f(x,y), |\mathbf L| = 5,  \nabla_{\mathbf L} f(x,y) = 10 \Rightarrow \lambda  = 2$

On putting this value in $ \nabla f(x,y) = \lambda \mathbf L    $ , $a = b = -1$

Comment: Very powerful,I admire, how can I think like you?

Comment: Please don't dislike me.